# When $\gcd{(N, r-s)}=\gcd{(N, r^{-1}-s^{-1})}=g$, relation between $(r-s)/g$ and $(r^{-1}-s^{-1})/g$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $N$ be a positive integer and $r$ and $s$ be two integers in $\mathbb{Z}_N$ such that $\gcd{(N, r)}=\gcd{(N, s)}=1$.

It is true that $\gcd{(N, r-s)}=\gcd{(N, r^{-1}-s^{-1})}$, where both $r^{-1}$ and $s^{-1}$ are the multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_N$.

So we can let $\gcd{(N, r-s)}=\gcd{(N, r^{-1}-s^{-1})}=g$ and $r-s = ag$ and $r^{-1}-s^{-1} = bg$.

Question) I want to know if it is true that $a$ is odd, then $b$ is also odd.

Answer (score 1):

No. For one thing, $r^{-1}$ and $s^{-1}$ are only well defined modulo $N$; so when $N$ is odd (the only nontrivial case), then you can change the parity of $r^{-1}-s^{-1}$ by adding $N$ to one of them.

Even if you insist that $1\le r^{-1},s^{-1} \le N$, the answer is still no. For example, when $N$ is odd, let $r=2$ and $s=1$ (so that $r-s$ is odd). Then $s^{-1}=1$ and $r^{-1}=(N+1)/2$, so that $r^{-1}-s^{-1} = (N-1)/2$ is odd when $N\equiv3$ (mod $4$) but even when $N\equiv1$ (mod $4$).

Comment: When $N$ is even, does that hold? (In this case, both $r-s$ and $r^{-1}-s^{-1}$ is even...)